# how to create object from specific another object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have this type of object which fetched from Redis

```
{
        'username': 'hamet',
        'username_Type': 'string',
        'meta': 'object',
        'meta_Type': 'object',
        'meta.avatar': '/avatar.png',
        'meta.avatar_Type': 'string',
        'meta.active': 'false',
        'meta.active_Type': 'boolean',
        'meta.someArr': 'array',
        'meta.someArr_Type': 'array',
        'meta.someArr.0': 'object',
        'meta.someArr.0_Type': 'object',
        'meta.someArr.0.field': '123',
        'meta.someArr.0.field_Type': 'number',
        'meta.someArr.1': 'object',
        'meta.someArr.1_Type': 'object',
        'meta.someArr.1.field': '321',
        'meta.someArr.1.field_Type': 'number'
}
```

all i want is convert this object to valid object like this:

```
{
        username: 'hamet',
        meta: {
            avatar: '/avatar.png',
            active: false,
            someArr: [
                { field: 123 },
                { field: 321 }
            ]

        }
}
```

once i created iterated function, but there was a problem with that. is it possible to convert with Iterated function and how?

Comment: @melpomene if you could write a code or function to me, it will be awesome or any solution to me how to convert?

Comment: That's not what SO is for. If you want someone to write code for you, hire a programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create object with value types that you will use for creating new instances of different data types and then use `reduce()` method to build your object.

```js
const data = {"username":"hamet","username_Type":"string","meta":"object","meta_Type":"object","meta.avatar":"/avatar.png","meta.avatar_Type":"string","meta.active":"false","meta.active_Type":"boolean","meta.someArr":"array","meta.someArr_Type":"array","meta.someArr.0":"object","meta.someArr.0_Type":"object","meta.someArr.0.field":"123","meta.someArr.0.field_Type":"number","meta.someArr.1":"object","meta.someArr.1_Type":"object","meta.someArr.1.field":"321","meta.someArr.1.field_Type":"number"}

const result = {}
const create = {'string': String,'number': Number,'boolean': Boolean,'array': Array,'object': Object}
const findType = (key, obj) => obj[key]

Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
  if (!key.includes('Type')) {
    key.split('.').reduce((r, e, i, arr) => {
      let type = findType(key + '_Type', data);
      let value = create[data[key]] || arr[i + 1] ? new create[type] : new create[type](data[key]).valueOf()
      if (data[key] == 'false') value = false
      r[e] = r[e] || value;
      return r[e]
    }, result)
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: it's look like what i want; but what is `new create[type]`?

Comment: Updated so now value types work before everything was string.

Comment: Well it will create new instance of data type you have in your object, so for array it will create new array, string => new String ...

Comment: If its false we need to hardcode false because new Boolean('false') = true

Answer (score 2):

Get an array of keys with [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out the `_Type` keys. [Sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) the keys to ensure that parents (shorter) keys are first, since keys` order in an object is not ensured.

[Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) the array of keys, and for each key get it's value by type. If the type is not object/array use the actual key value. Iterate the result object with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), until you get to the leaf. Add the key with the value.

```js
const obj = {"meta.someArr.1.field":"321","username":"hamet","username_Type":"string","meta":"object","meta_Type":"object","meta.avatar":"/avatar.png","meta.avatar_Type":"string","meta.active":"false","meta.active_Type":"boolean","meta.someArr":"array","meta.someArr_Type":"array","meta.someArr.0":"object","meta.someArr.0_Type":"object","meta.someArr.0.field":"123","meta.someArr.0.field_Type":"number","meta.someArr.1":"object","meta.someArr.1_Type":"object","meta.someArr.1.field_Type":"number"};

const byType = {
  object: Object,
  array: Array
};

const result = Object.keys(obj)
  .filter((k) => !k.includes('_Type')) // remove Type keys
  .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length) // ensures that shorter (parent) keys are first
  .reduce((r, k) => {
    const type = obj[`${k}_Type`];

    const valueByType = byType[type] && byType[type]();
    const value = valueByType ? valueByType : obj[k];
    const keys = k.split('.');

    let current = r;

    keys.forEach((key, i) => {   
      if(!(key in current)) current[key] = value;
      else current = current[key];
    });

    return r;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  const result = {};

  function apply(obj, value, key, ...keys) {
    if(keys.length) {
     apply(obj[key] || (obj[key] = {}), value ...keys);
    } else {
     obj[key] = value;
   }
 }

 for(const [key, value] of Object.entries(yourObj))
   apply(result, value, ...key.split("."));
```

You could use a recursive approach to generate the nested structure. I havent included a check if key is a number so that it creates an array, thats your job ;)

If you prefer functional programming:

```
  const apply = (obj, value, ...keys) => keys.slice(1).reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] || (obj[key] = {}), obj)[keys.pop()] = value;
```

Comment: please note that this script uses a newer JS format, you might have to downgrade the syntax

Comment: @zedling `fetched from Redis` -> nodejs -> ES7

Comment: tnx, it will be run in node.js environment